# How to display clicked component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, jsx

I have a list of components using react hooks now I would like on clicking the component it should open the settings component and display the clicked component.

Here is codesandbox: [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-component-forked-fo6mb)

here is How I display the components list in app.js

```
import * as data from "./Components/CompList";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App(props) {
  let components = data.complist;
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {components.map(function (Component, id) {
        return (
          <div
            className="comp-list"
            key={id}
            onClick={() => {
              history.push(`/settings/${id}`);
            }}
          >
            <Component />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is how I display them in settings

```
import * as data from "./CompList";
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Settings = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const { templateId } = match.params;
  let templates = data.complist;

  let SelecteComponent = templates.map(function (Component, idx) {
    if (idx === Number(templateId)) {
      return Component;
    }
    return Component;
  });
  console.log("selected", SelecteComponent);
  return (
    <div className="selected-component">
      <SelecteComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

**Unfortunately it's not displaying the clicked component in the settings component**

What do I need to change to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probabely never see your `console.log` statement on `Settings.js` because the root never go on `Settings.js`.

Your basic exemple must look at this :

```
const BasicExample = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <App />} />
        {/* here I use the `:templateId` to say to react-router than some params muse be inside the route, and the syntaxe `component={Settings}` is better than `render={...}` */}
        <Route exact path="/settings/:templateId" component={Settings} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

When you do that, you can simply take the templateId using props :

```js
const Settings = ({ match }) => {
  const { templateId } = match.params;
  ...
}
```

And your function must be a `array.find()` to have only one element as result :

```js
  let SelecteComponent = templates.find(function (Component, idx) {
    if (idx === Number(templateId)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

[Here is my complete exemple on codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-component-forked-98p7f?file=/src/Components/Settings.js:171-325)

Comment: Thanks man exactly this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Updated Code: (tested in your codesandbox playground)

Components/A.js

```
import React from "react";

const A = () => {
  return (
    <div className="table-1">
      <h1>Table one</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default A;
```

Components/B.js

```
import React from "react";

const B = () => {
  return (
    <div className="table-2">
      <h1>Table Two</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default B;
```

Components/Complist.js

```
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";

export const Complist = [{Component: A, id: 'a'}, {Component: B, id: 'b'}];
```

Components/Settings

```
import React from "react";
import * as data from "./CompList";
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Settings = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const { templateId } = match.params;
  let templates = data.complist;

  let SelecteComponent = templates.find(t => t.id === templateId)
  return (
    <div className="selected-component">
      <SelecteComponent.Component />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import * as data from "./Components/CompList";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App(props) {
  let components = data.complist;
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {components.map(function ({Component, id}) {
        return (
          <div
            className="comp-list"
            key={id}
            onClick={() => {
              history.push(`/settings/${id}`);
            }}
          >
            <Component />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Settings from "./Components/Settings";

const BasicExample = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <App />} />
        <Route exact path="/settings/:templateId" render={() => <Settings />} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: It would be better to use explicit ID instead of index, like this 
```export const Complist = [{Component: A, id: 'a'}, {Component: B, id: 'b'}];```